# Change rails ActiveRecord last ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class EmployeeTrainingRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

When I do:

```
EmployeeTrainingRecord.all
```

I get:

```
SELECT "employee_training_records".* FROM "employee_training_records"
```

This is all pretty standard stuff so far...  Now comes the interesting part...

When I do:

```
EmployeeTrainingRecord.last
```

I get:

```
SELECT "employee_training_records".* FROM "employee_training_records" ORDER BY "employee_training_records"."" DESC LIMIT 1
```

Which of course errors on the `"employee_training_records".""`.

Unfortunately, I did not create this table and do not have the migration available.

While I was writing this question, it occurred to me that the column used for ordering by last and first is probably the primary key.  And after some investigation into the ActiveRecord guides, I found that you can set the primary key inside the model, and doing so fixed the issue I was originally asking about. That said, I have a new question:

**Is there a way to change the column that last and first order by (aside from changing the primary_key of course)?**

Something like `self.order_column`?

I get that I could just do order().limit(), but it seems like it might be useful to order by a timestamp for the purposes of last and first (I know that default_scope is widely accepted as a way of adding default orderings, however, default_scope has some nasty side-effects and I do not want to always apply the ordering either).

Answer (score 0):

add this to your model:

```
default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }
```

you can use whatever attribute you want instead of created_at.

Comment: There are some complicated circumstances within my application that prevent me from using default_scopes on most models... (under certain circumstances default_scopes do some strange things that you wouldn't expect)

Comment: got ya, could you create a class method that just orders by column?